# How to create header with menu and search box in blogger?

Tags: blogger

I want to create a responsive header with menu bar and with responsive search box in blogger.

Comment: Example - like on this blogger [Ras in Hindi](https://www.mycoaching.in/2018/09/Ras-In-Hindi.html)

Comment: show some code what you have tried or some error?